# How can I call hook_user_presave() only when an account is updated, not created?

Tags: hooks

I want to call [hook_user_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) only when an account is updated, not created.  However, the API docs state:

> A user account is about to be created or updated.

Is there a way to check whether I am getting a new account or an update to an existing account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On creation `$account` will have `is_new` set to true. And other minor differences, like it'll not have `created` property set yet.

```
object(stdClass)#92 (18) {
  ["uid"]=>
  int(0)
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(3) "::1"
  ["roles"]=>
  array(3) {
    [2]=>
    bool(true)
    [3]=>
    int(0)
    [4]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["cache"]=>
  int(0)
  ["administer_users"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "test"
  ["mail"]=>
  string(14) "test@example.com"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(3) "aaa"
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["notify"]=>
  int(0)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Warsaw"
  ["signature"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["picture"]=>
  NULL
  ["picture_delete"]=>
  int(0)
  ["picture_upload"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["signature_format"]=>
  string(13) "filtered_html"
  ["init"]=>
  string(14) "test@example.com"
  ["is_new"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While creating the new user $account->uid will be 0 within this hook.

So you can use something below,

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if ($account->uid) {
    // DO your operations.
  }
}
```